# Cannot send authentication in header of project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, authorization

So basically I'm working on integrating a web API into my project from an externally hosted source.. But the xml is stored behind basic authentication. So I've been advised that I need to parse some authentication into the header of my HTTP request when contacting the location of the XML.

Here's what I'm working with at the moment:

I've created a controller, my code is as follows:

```
namespace com.tortoise.Controllers
{
    public class VebraController : ApiController
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");

        string username = "user";
        string password = "password";

        string usernamePassword = ("username + : + password");

        CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
        new cache.add Uri(url), "Basic", new class NetworkCredential(username, password));
        request.Credentials = cache; 
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "  // <- space here.
        + Convert.ToBase64String()(new Int64 ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes (usernamePassword));
        // Get the token from the response: 
        string token = response.GetResponseHeader("Token");
}
```

Any help is great. I'm receiving errors in CredentialCache, ASCIIEncoding, ToBase64String(), GetBytes() and GetResponseHeader().

Comment: *What errors?* Please do not expect us to read your mind.

Comment: `new cache.add Uri(url), "Basic", new class NetworkCredential(username, password)); `this is not valid C# that is one of your problems. You don't need the `new` keyword and you are not calling `Add` correctly.

Comment: `string usernamePassword = ("username + : + password");` also not sure if you are trying to concatenate strings here but you need to put the plus sign outside the quotations if you are

Comment: Sorry eddie. so here are the errors i'm experiencing after implementing your pointers. CredentialCache now appears to work. NetworkCredential returns = "Method must have a type", the username , password which follows returns is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: cache.add returns = is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'. Request does the same. ToBase64String is a 'method'bus is used as a 'type'. GetBytes returns Method must have a return type. Lastly the (usernamePassword)); returns the "is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Where do you declare `url`?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with `Convert.ToBase64String()(new Int64 ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes (usernamePassword));` this line

Comment: The url is first referenced at the top of the controller in the  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
 Also I believe the base line is to convert the username & password combination into an encoded string that can be included in the HTTP request to the server where the API resides for it to then be decoded to authenticate my access to the feed.

Comment: You are not creating a variable called "url" there, though. So that is a problem. You need to declare a variable called url if you are going to call it when creating that URI

Comment: So I can't hard code the url in there?

Comment: You can if you are actually putting in a URL string there. But if you want to reference it later you need to put it in a variable.

Comment: Right ok i'll look to do that in that case. Any thoughts on the potentially other issues i'm facing? Thanks for your help so far by the way, this has been stumping me all week.

Comment: See my posted answer, tried to fix as much as I could. You need to declare the variable `response` to use it, but I don't know what you are meaning to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have fixed your code a bit. It should compile now, assuming you have actually declared the variables you are using. I can't do that for you. *Please read the comments.* You seem to need a lot of practice with C# syntax and the language in general, you had a lot of invalid C# in there. Hope this helps.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

   string username = "user";
   string password = "password";

   //here I am declaring the NetworkCredentials. You do not need to put 'new class'
   NetworkCredential myCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password);
   string usernamePassword = (username + password); //I assume you meant to concatenate them

    CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
    cache.Add((Uri)url, "Basic", myCredentials); //you must declare url, not sure what you want it to be 

    request.Credentials = cache; 
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "  // <- space here.
    + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(usernamePassword)); //fixed this
    // Get the token from the response: 
    string token = response.GetResponseHeader("Token"); //you need to declare response somewhere
```

Comment: I agree, Like I mentioned in the original post, I've started with C# & ASP.Net this week.

Comment: I suggest you take things slow and go one line at a time, making sure you understand what you are doing, so you can just debug compiler errors as they appear instead of having a giant monster method full of scary bugs :)